# I need help going through data in JSON format with python

Tags: python, json

I am new here. I've been having some problems with my code.

I have JSON in a format like this:

```
[{"word":"ingenious","score":1828,"numSyllables":3}, 
{"word":"heterogeneous","score":1139,"numSyllables":5}]
```

I want to use python to iterate over each key, then take the value and print it so each **word** is on a new line with *nymSyllables* in brackets next to it. The expected outcome is like this:

```
ingenious (3)
heterogeneous (5)
```

Comment: Where is the code you having problems with?

Comment: Here @HenryYik repl.it/@rohinarya12/Web-Scrape-2

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the objects in the list and print the desired string for each one of them:

```
arr = [{"word":"ingenious","score":1828,"numSyllables":3}, 
{"word":"heterogeneous","score":1139,"numSyllables":5}]

for obj in arr:
    print('{} ({})'.format(obj['word'], obj['numSyllables']))
```

Output:

```
ingenious (3)
heterogeneous (5)
```

You could also do this in one line if you want:

```
print('\n'.join('{} ({})'.format(obj['word'], obj['numSyllables']) for obj in arr))
```

Output:

```
ingenious (3)
heterogeneous (5)
```

Comment: I think this would work, however, it gives me an error: TypeError: string indices must be integers. My entire code is at this link which you can fork and play around with https://repl.it/@rohinarya12/Web-Scrape-2

Comment: @Rohin12 I just looked into your code and it seems that your `arr` is a string, turn it into an array using `import ast;
arr = ast.literal_eval(arr)` first and try it, [it works](https://repl.it/@MrGeek/Web-Scrape-2).